# Width of tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing, tabs, width, jtabbedpane

How can I set a full width for a tabbed pane? I've tried working with the following code:

```
UIDefaults def = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
    def.put( "TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 250) );
```

But, it doesn't seem to increase the size fully, whatever I work with. It either creates two rows, or isn't full length.

Picture to understand the problem:
http://s8.postimage.org/lr47nm9tx/tabbedpanefull.png

Comment: you need to tell more. It seems like a Layout effect.